# $accessToken is returning null facebook oauth

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

Hi im facing a problem which i couldnt find solution on net ,

this is how my code looks like

```
      session_start();
      require_once "Facebook/autoload.php";

$FB = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '********',
    'app_secret' => '***********',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10'
]);

$helper = $FB->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo "Response Exception: " . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
} catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "SDK Exception: " . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
```

I have debugged two variables from this code

```
var_dump($helper); // returns
    object(Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper)#10 (4) { ["oAuth2Client":protected]=> object(Facebook\Authentication\OAuth2Client)#11 (4) { ["app":protected]=> object(Facebook\FacebookApp)#3 (2) { ["id":protected]=> string(15) "**********" ["secret":protected]=> string(32) "*************" } ["client":protected]=> object(Facebook\FacebookClient)#4 (2) { ["enableBetaMode":protected]=> bool(false) ["httpClientHandler":protected]=> object(Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient)#5 (4) { ["curlErrorMessage":protected]=> string(0) "" ["curlErrorCode":protected]=> int(0) ["rawResponse":protected]=> NULL ["facebookCurl":protected]=> object(Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl)#6 (1) { ["curl":protected]=> NULL } } } ["graphVersion":protected]=> string(5) "v2.10" ["lastRequest":protected]=> NULL } ["urlDetectionHandler":protected]=> object(Facebook\Url\FacebookUrlDetectionHandler)#8 (0) { } ["persistentDataHandler":protected]=> object(Facebook\PersistentData\FacebookSessionPersistentDataHandler)#9 (1) { ["sessionPrefix":protected]=> string(6) "FBRLH_" } ["pseudoRandomStringGenerator":protected]=> object(Facebook\PseudoRandomString\McryptPseudoRandomStringGenerator)#7 (0) { } }
```

and this

```
   var_dump($accessToken); // return NULL
```

I dont know what going wrong .

Im using version=v2.10  and SDK 5

How to fix $accessToken ?

Comment: There is no `accessToken` in dumped `$helper`, so `getAccessToken()` can't work.

Comment: How do i add it ?

Comment: So where are you sending the user to the login flow …?

Answer (score -1):

If `$accessToken` is `null`, possibly the user denied the request. It is fully documented in [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper/5.0.0). You should try to see if any dumped from the helper `$helper->getError()`.

```
# login-callback.php
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([/* . . . */]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
  // Logged in!
  $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

  // Now you can redirect to another page and use the
  // access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
} elseif ($helper->getError()) {
  // The user denied the request
  exit;
}
```